# Error when connecting Mysql thru PDO, but not when using basic mysqli commands SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

Both connection classes are under the same project:

1) This first class runs fine and everything works right as it should be:

```
<?php
class DAO{

    protected $servidor;
    protected $base;
    protected $usuario;
    protected $senha;
    protected $conexao;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->base = "ima";
        $this->usuario = 'admin';
        $this->senha = 'wd4567';
        $this->servidor = 'localhost';
        $this->abrirConexao();
        $this->selecionar();        
    }

    protected function abrirConexao(){
        $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($this->servidor, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
        if (!$this->conexao) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
//      echo "Connected successfully";
        mysqli_set_charset($this->conexao, "utf8");


    }
```

2)This second connection class using PDO returns the error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. But as far as I can see, the data set is the same... Please need help on this:

```
<?php
/*  
  * Constantes de parâmetros para configuração da conexão  
  */  
 define('HOST', 'localhost');  
 define('DBNAME', 'ima');  
 define('CHARSET', 'utf8');  
 define('USER', 'admin');  
 define('PASSWORD', 'wd4567');  

 class Conexao {  

   /*  
    * Atributo estático para instância do PDO  
    */  
   private static $pdo;

   /*  
    * Escondendo o construtor da classe  
    */ 
   private function __construct() {  
     //  
   } 

   /*  
    * Método estático para retornar uma conexão válida  
    * Verifica se já existe uma instância da conexão, caso não, configura uma nova conexão  
    */  
   public static function getInstance() {  
     if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {  
       try {  
         $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);  
         echo("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . "; ". USER ."  ". PASSWORD . $opcoes);
         self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . "; ", USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);  
       } catch (PDOException $e) {  
         print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();  
       }  
     }  
     return self::$pdo;  
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Appreciate any help on this, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing all white-space in the DSN?  Something like:

```
"mysql:host=" . HOST . ";dbname=" . DBNAME . ";charset=" . CHARSET . ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
class Conexao { 
    private static $pdo;

    public static function getInstance() {  
        if (!self::$pdo) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ima;charset=utf8;',
                'admin',
                'wd4567',
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
                      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                ));
        }
        return self::$pdo;  
    }
}

// Create connection
$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
// Close connection
$pdo = null;
```

Comment: Please [do not catch error exceptions to report them](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors).

Comment: Besides, you kept the error in your code, which makes your answer off topic.

Comment: Is it ok now? @YourCommonSense when you see something in-complete you can propose an edit :)

Comment: Well, when I started editing your answer, I noticed many other errors, that makes your code unusable. I'd suggest you to try this code on your local test server and debug it until you make it work. You'll learn a lot of useful things during the process. After fixing your code, I'll suggest my edits.

Comment: and yes the error is on declaring this PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION on Guido's code @YourCommonSense

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. At the moment there are two flaws with your answer: it doesn't answer the question. It doesn't work.

Comment: Let me repeat my advise: set up a local testing server on your PC, and use it to verify the code you write in your answers. I am following this practice  for many years, and can assure you it extremely useful.

Comment: i have not tested it, but i will do shortly.

Comment: Yes it was buggy @YourCommonSense thank you i have fixed the errors and tested it this is fully working. Created a PDO.txt file in log folder with the following data.

Comment: Connected to MySQL Server 11-05-2016 14:10:06
Closed connection to MySQL Server 11-05-2016 14:10:06
Connected to MySQL Server 11-05-2016 14:10:08
Closed connection to MySQL Server 11-05-2016 14:10:08

Comment: But the OP had a static method that returns a PDO instance, while you made it quite the opposite - a non-static method thet is just setting a class property. for such a case I fail to see any benefit from such a class. Everything it can offer is offered by raw PDO as well

Comment: However, I prefer to have database credentials to be set outside the class - as you can see, it is inconvenient to hardcode them - makes your code not interchengeable.

Comment: Thanks for all effort, I just added the PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, as you two have reccomended. But the error message persists, trying to figure out if I'm doing anything wrong... Couldn't it be some config parameter(just a guess)?

Comment: @Guido please try the code as is in your setup, it is tested and working. Start changing the code and adding things that you want gradually in order to have an easy job debugging in general.

Comment: Yes, thanks Peter. When using Xampp in my local server it works and my first example too(sorry, I should have tested localy before)... Seems it is some server configuration issue... Still seeking what to do now...

Comment: @peter. Just found the solution... FINALLY! Seems the OPENSHIFT server uses a HOST and PORT in a different way in the php configuration file for PDO. So I change the HOST and PORT values for the ones below: **define('HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
 define('PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));**

Comment: Thanks for all help. Not sure if I must change the question status or something like that.